# Laravel CRUD delete not working on foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a foreign relationship with category_id column in database but while deleting i get error.
This is my code for delete:

```
  public function destroy($id)
{
    $category = Category::find($id);
    $category->delete();
    Session::flash('success', 'The category was successfully deleted.');
    return redirect()->route('categories.index');
}
```

Error i seen is :

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`fitilicious`.`products`, CONSTRAINT `products_category_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`)) (SQL: delete from `categories` where `id` = 2)
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

My bet is on the foreign key being set to ON DELETE RESTRICT instead of CASCADE.

> Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`fitilicious`.`products`, CONSTRAINT `products_category_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`)) (SQL: delete from `categories` where `id` = 2)

This tells us that there is a row in table "products" which is referencing the category you are attempting to delete.

- ON DELETE CASCADE will also delete the product.
- ON DELETE RESTRICT will prevent deletion of a non-empty category
- ON DELETE SET NULL will delete the category and set category_id to NULL in products table

Each has its uses, but you need to choose which one you need.

Comment: but what do we write code in laravel delete to accomplish this